# Restrict type by super class in interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface, typeof

I would like to create an interface which defined a set of key value pares where the value is restricted to a typeof classWhichExtendsSpecificSuperClass.

For instance, this interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
     key: typeof SuperClass
}
```

and this base class:

```
class BaseClass extends SuperClass {...}
```

Applied in this way:

```
function myFunction(arg: MyInterface) {...};

myFunction({
   key: BaseClass
});
```

The above code would tell me that typeof BaseClass is not assignable to typeof SuperClass.

Now I get that what I am doing is not correct, but is it possible any other way? I would like to ensure that the only allowable values for "key" are typeof classes that extend SuperClass?

If I was dealing in functions I could use generics, but as far as I know there is no way to express a generic at the object property.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, the following code works for me class SuperClass {
    nr: number;
}

interface MyInterface {
    key: typeof SuperClass
}

class BaseClass extends SuperClass {
    s: string;
}

function myFunction(arg: MyInterface) {
    var c = new arg.key();
}

myFunction({
    key: BaseClass
});

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? I had this compiling and stepped away from the project and now it seems to have problem.

Comment: I am using 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the classes that extend `SuperClass` have compatible constructor parameters, your code should work with no error.  For example:

```
class SuperClass {
  superValue: string;
}
interface MyInterface {
     key: typeof SuperClass
}
class BaseClass extends SuperClass {
  baseValue: string;
}
function myFunction(arg: MyInterface) { };
myFunction({
   key: BaseClass // no error
});
```

There's no problem here because both `BaseClass` and `SuperClass` can be constructed with zero arguments.  But if you change the constructor of `BaseClass`:

```
class BaseClass extends SuperClass {
  baseValue: string;
  constructor(someArgument: string) {
    super();
  }
}
```

you will get the error you mentioned when you call `myFunction()`:

```
Argument of type '{ key: typeof BaseClass; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyInterface'.
  Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof BaseClass' is not assignable to type 'typeof SuperClass'.
```

Now, depending on what you want to do with `MyInterface`, that error might be important.  Do you intend to take the `key` property of `MyInterface` value and use it to construct an instance of some subclass of `SuperClass`?  For example:

```
declare let myInterface: MyInterface;
let someInstance = new myInterface.key();
```

If so, then you need to make sure that the class constructor accepts the right number and type of arguments, and that error is helping you.  It's telling you to change the `BaseClass` constructor to be compatible with `SuperClass`'s constructor.  For example, if we make `someArgument` optional:

```
class BaseClass extends SuperClass {
  baseValue: string;
  constructor(someArgument?: string) {
    super();
  }
}
```

then the error goes away because `new SubClass()` will now work with no arguments.

---

If you *don't* intend to use `MyInterface` to construct instances, and you *don't* care about the number and type of arguments that the constructors take, and you just want it to hold *some* class constructor for some reason... then you can do this:

```
type Constructor<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T; // any number and type of arguments
}
interface MyInterface {
     key: Constructor<SuperClass>
}
```

Now `myFunction()` will work even if the constructor signatures are incompatible.  That's because you don't really want to restrict yourself to `typeof SuperClass`; you'd like to accept *any* constructor that creates a `SuperClass`, and that's what `Constructor<SuperClass>` means.  So the error goes away and you're happy.

---

Hopefully one of those two solutions will work for you.  Good luck!