# TypeScript convert subtype to supertype and remove extra fields

Tags: typescript

If we were to have these types:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}
interface Agent extends Person {
  code: number;
}
```

and have this code:

```
const agent: Agent = {
  name: 'name',
  code: 123
}
```

How would you cast the type `Agent` into `Person` and remove the code field? When I try to do this:

```
const person: Person = agent as Person
console.log(person) // Still contains the fields of agent
```

This is a simple example, but in my real usecase the object has a lot more fields. I've also tried:

```
person: Person = {
...agent
}
```

Another post I looked at that didn't work for my case:
[Restrict type by super class in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853471/restrict-type-by-super-class-in-interface).

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378612/how-to-cast-object-to-another-type-and-remove-unneeded-fields-in-typescript)?

Comment: @DavidScholz Oh wow, I did plenty of googling but didn't find that, thank you

Comment: If the number of extra properties of Agent is limited, you could do `const { code, ...person} = agent`

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl yea that's what I surmised I could do, but for my usecase it makes it a little impractical/annoying. I could always just do it once and create a method to do the conversions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting doesn't mean that the real value inside what is casted will change. It is for the developper to tell TypeScript "trust me on this, I know what is inside". It makes sense only during development, not on runtime.

For the the development part, maybe [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) will help. You could do for example something like this (if you wanna keep some fields from `Agent` inside `Person`):

```
type Person = Pick<Agent, "name"|"address">;
```

Comment: I haven't seen the utility types such as pick, that's really awesome I'll likely use it in the future. Looking at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378612/how-to-cast-object-to-another-type-and-remove-unneeded-fields-in-typescript) it's not possible to remove the extra fields. Thanks a lot for the support

Comment: Yeah you can't with casting. And yeah Utility Types are great in some cases. Glad I could pass the info !